# How to make ttk.Scale behave more like tk.Scale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Several Tk widgets also exist in Ttk versions. Usually they have the same general behaviour, but use "styles" and "themes" rather than per-instance appearance attributes (such as `bg`, etc...). This is good, as the Ttk widgets take the "standard appearance" of the OS's window manager by default, without needing to configure anything about appearance.

However, for some reason the `ttk.Scale` widget does not have two very useful options of the `tk.Scale` widget: `showvalue` and `tickinterval` (see [reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Scale.html)). This is strange as those are more about behaviour than about look.

It would be great to "immitate" these two options while keeping a `ttk` look.
The following code is my clumsy attempt at this. The question is: is there a better way? (besides encapsulating the whole thing in a class, obviously) and how would one reasonably get a semi-automated `tickinterval` substitute (rather than doing it "by hand" as in the code below).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# initial setup
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)

#################################################################
# create a tk slider showing current value and ticks
# (showvalue=True is the default)
tkslider = tk.Scale(frame, from_=-4, to=4,
                    orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, tickinterval=2)
#################################################################

#################################################################
# create a ttk slider showing current value and ticks
# use a ttk frame to get ttk style background
ttkslider = ttk.Frame(frame)
# define a callback function to update the value label
def ttk_slider_callback(value):
    # 'value' seems to be a string - bug or feature?
    value_label.config(text=round(float(value)))
    # 'text' can apparently be an int and gets converted into str
    # (...) possibly do other stuff
# decompose frame into two ttk labels and a ttk scale
value_label = ttk.Label(ttkslider, text=0)
actual_slider = ttk.Scale(ttkslider, from_=-4, to=4,
                          command=ttk_slider_callback)
# (orient=tk.HORIZONTAL is the default)
ticks_label = ttk.Label(ttkslider, text='  -4 -2  0  2  4   ')
# put it all together
value_label.grid()
actual_slider.grid()
ticks_label.grid()
#################################################################

# final setup
tkslider.grid(row=0, column=0)
ttkslider.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

The result of the previous code, before actualy "sliding" the Scales, may look like this, with the Tk Scale on the left and the Ttk Scale on the right (will vary obviously per OS / window manager):

[image]

Comment: Some ideas: 1) For your `showvalue` implementation you can use single `StringVar` for both `Scale` and `Label` widgets. Unfortunately  `ttk.Scale` lacks `digits` option, which controls string representation of a value. Anyway, in my opinion, it's OK as is right now. 2) `tickinterval` implementation is more tricky: you can try to generate all "tick" values (since you know desired `tickinterval`), labels and [coords](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_scale.htm#M23) (via `tk` call `root.tk.call(actual_slider, 'coords', str(round(float(value))))`) and place these labels relative to the `Scale`.

Comment: @CommonSense 1) I had actually tried to use a `StringVar` for inter-widget communication before posting, but sadly it results in the display of floats with lots of digits, which actually messes up the label position as well -- hence the "manual" rounding of the number to get a neater display. 2) thanks for the link, it might prove useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place in an automated way both the ticks and the label showing the value using `place` and their position x (in pixels) given by the formula:

```
x = ((value - start) / extent) * (width - sliderlength) + sliderlength / 2
```

with:

- `value`: the value of the tick
- `start`: the starting point of the scale (i.e. the `from` option)
- `extent`: end - start
- `width`: the width of the scale

`((value - start) / extent)` gives the position in percent and then, I just have to multiply it by the length of the scale, but taking into account the length of the slider.

Then place the tick with:
`place(in_=self.scale, bordermode='outside', x=x, rely=1, anchor='n')`
(use `rely=0, anchor='s'` for the label showing the value)

And below is the full code. I have also added support for the `digits` option.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TtkScale(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.showvalue = kwargs.pop('showvalue', True)
        self.tickinterval = kwargs.pop('tickinterval', 0)
        self.digits = kwargs.pop('digits', '0')
        
        if 'command' in kwargs:
            # add self.display_value to the command
            fct = kwargs['command']
            
            def cmd(value):
                fct(value)
                self.display_value(value)
                
            kwargs['command'] = cmd
        else:
            kwargs['command'] = self.display_value
            
        self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, **kwargs)
        
        # get slider length
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style_name = kwargs.get('style', '%s.TScale' % (str(self.scale.cget('orient')).capitalize()))
        self.sliderlength = style.lookup(style_name, 'sliderlength', default=30)
        
        self.extent = kwargs['to'] - kwargs['from_']
        self.start = kwargs['from_']
        # showvalue
        if self.showvalue:
            ttk.Label(self, text=' ').grid(row=0)
            self.label = ttk.Label(self, text='0')
            self.label.place(in_=self.scale, bordermode='outside', x=0, y=0, anchor='s')
            self.display_value(self.scale.get())
            
        self.scale.grid(row=1, sticky='ew')
        
        # ticks
        if self.tickinterval:
            ttk.Label(self, text=' ').grid(row=2)
            self.ticks = []
            self.ticklabels = []
            nb_interv = round(self.extent/self.tickinterval)
            formatter = '{:.' + str(self.digits) + 'f}'
            for i in range(nb_interv + 1):
                tick = kwargs['from_'] + i * self.tickinterval
                self.ticks.append(tick)
                self.ticklabels.append(ttk.Label(self, text=formatter.format(tick)))
                self.ticklabels[i].place(in_=self.scale, bordermode='outside', x=0, rely=1, anchor='n')
            self.place_ticks()

        self.scale.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)
        
    def convert_to_pixels(self, value):
        return ((value - self.start)/ self.extent) * (self.scale.winfo_width()- self.sliderlength) + self.sliderlength / 2
        
    def display_value(self, value):
        # position (in pixel) of the center of the slider
        x = self.convert_to_pixels(float(value))
        # pay attention to the borders
        half_width = self.label.winfo_width() / 2
        if x + half_width > self.scale.winfo_width():
            x = self.scale.winfo_width() - half_width
        elif x - half_width < 0:
            x = half_width
        self.label.place_configure(x=x)
        formatter = '{:.' + str(self.digits) + 'f}'
        self.label.configure(text=formatter.format(float(value)))
    
    def place_ticks(self):
        # first tick 
        tick = self.ticks[0]
        label = self.ticklabels[0]
        x = self.convert_to_pixels(tick)
        half_width = label.winfo_width() / 2
        if x - half_width < 0:
            x = half_width
        label.place_configure(x=x)
        # ticks in the middle
        for tick, label in zip(self.ticks[1:-1], self.ticklabels[1:-1]):
            x = self.convert_to_pixels(tick)
            label.place_configure(x=x)
        # last tick
        tick = self.ticks[-1]
        label = self.ticklabels[-1]
        x = self.convert_to_pixels(tick)
        half_width = label.winfo_width() / 2
        if x + half_width > self.scale.winfo_width():
            x = self.scale.winfo_width() - half_width
        label.place_configure(x=x)
        
    def on_configure(self, event):
        """Redisplay the ticks and the label so that they adapt to the new size of the scale."""
        self.display_value(self.scale.get())
        self.place_ticks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x300')
    style = ttk.Style(root)
    style.configure('my.Horizontal.TScale', sliderlength=10)

    s1 = tk.Scale(root, orient='horizontal', tickinterval=0.2, from_=-1, 
                  to=1, showvalue=True, resolution=0.1,  sliderlength=10)
    s2 = TtkScale(root, style='my.Horizontal.TScale', orient='horizontal', 
                  tickinterval=0.2, from_=-1, to=1, showvalue=True, 
                  digits=1)

    ttk.Label(root, text='tk.Scale').pack()
    s1.pack(fill='x')
    ttk.Label(root, text='ttk.Scale').pack()
    s2.pack(fill='x')

    root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

A more complete version of this widget is available in the [ttkwidgets](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkwidgets) module under the name TickScale.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have text next to the ttk.Scale, you need to use ttk.LabeledScale instead.